# How to install mimms on Mac using homebrew

Tags: homebrew, mms

How to install mimms on Mac using homebrew.
Earlier, I installed it using MacPorts but they are ugly and clutter the system a lot.
Therefore, on another machine I installed HomeBrew instead, which works fine except I am unable to find mimms on it. Googling results in nothing.

Comment: If semi-automatic installation is also an option you can install `libmms` via Homebrew and get the latest `mimms` release from `https://launchpad.net/mimms`. It's just a few Python scripts but they rely on `libmms.0.dylib` so after calling `make` you'll need to change the `cdll.LoadLibrary` call in `build/libmms.py` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the suggestions in the above comment into a formula for `mimms`:

https://github.com/stefanschmidt/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mimms.rb

It can be applied via the `brew install <URL>` mechanism.

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/stefanschmidt/homebrew/master/Library/Formula/mimms.rb
```

Update (2014-10-28): Meanwhile `mimms` is available from the main repository:

```
brew install mimms
```